# Variable inspection for import/export not working in VS Code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, babeljs

My project is using node.  I run my code thru babel and build with source maps.  VS Code will hit breakpoints fine and I can step thru code correctly but if I use import statements it does not allow me to inspect the variable at run-time.  Doing the same with require works fine.

[image]

In the screenshot when I require the ../settings file the config variable works fine, I can add to watch and even hover over and inspect.  But if I import from ../settings it shows 'not available'.